# Dynamically offset labels in a doughnut chart

Tags: javascript, text, charts, label

Using JavaScript, I have created program that takes an `<ol></ol>` of links and generates a doughnut chart, where each segment will be of equal size and contain the hyperlinked text. It is intended to act as a different method of navigation.

Here is an example output of my program:

[Doughnut chart program output, please view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8f1ig.png)

The doughnut chart is made by creating a series of segments that make a circle, a pie chart, and then placing a smaller circle in the center of this chart to make the doughnut chart.

Notice that, with the center hole added, the text needs an offset to be centered properly. However, the direction of this offset is dependent upon where the segment is on the chart.

The number of segments is equal to the number of `<li></li>` items in the `<ol></ol>`. The program will only be used on a list of a lengths between 3-9.

How could I have my code decide which offset to apply to each segment?

**My first idea:**

Create a switch statement to evaluate how many segments are in the chart. Then, apply an offset to each individual segment. E.G:

```js
   for (var i = 0; i < NumOfSegments; i++) {
    switch (NumOfSegments) {
      case 3:
        if (currentSegment == 0){
          //Apply offset for segment 1
        } else if (current segment == 1){
          //Apply offset for segment 2
        } else if (current segment == 2){
          //Apply offset for segment 3
        }
        break;
      case: 4:
        if (currentSegment == 0){
          //Apply offset for segment 1
        } else if (current segment == 1){
          //Apply offset for segment 2
        } else if (current segment == 2){
          //Apply offset for segment 3
        } } else if (current segment == 3){
          //Apply offset for segment 4
        }
        break;
      
      . . .
      
    }
  }
```

**My second idea**

This idea came to a halt as I wasn't sure on how to progress it. But:

Let n equal the total number of segments in the doughnut chart.
Let k equal n/2.

If the segment currently being drawn's position in the list is less than k, we know that the segment is on the left side of the chart.

Conversely, if the segment currently being drawn's position in the list is greater than k, we know that segment is on the right side of the list.

Therefore, using this, we can apply an offset in a direction generalized to that side of the list. However, I am not sure how - without using a method similar to my first idea - you could apply an offset more unique to each segment.

Any input would be gratefully received and appreciated. I have tried to explain this as best as I can, but if you have any questions, please ask.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you creating these charts to begin with? A chart library like chart.js? How are you placing the text in the correct areas to begin with?

Comment: @Matt I've not used any plugins. I've made my own doughnut chart, by creating a function that creates a segment and then repeatedly calling that function but editing the angle so all the segments create a circle. The labels are being added through treating each segment as a triangle, working out the midpoint, and using the fillText() method to add the text.

Comment: Where are you offsetting the text? To the center of the triangle? The center of where the text currently lies? Or elsewhere?